# Android: Programmatically Get IMG SRC from Image Gallery within WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm using a WebView which displays some nice HTML. One of the pictures should be chosen from the Picture Gallery and displayed within the WebView.

So, basically, I need Javascript to access Java (in order to open the Gallery), as well as Java to access Javascript (to get the result back)

I used the following code:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{    
      Context mContext;
      Uri currImageURI;
      JavaScriptInterface(Context c)
      {
          mContext = c;
      }

    public void imageFromGallery()
    {    
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {         
        String retResult="";
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {                
            if (requestCode == 1) 
            {
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                retResult=getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
            }
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:updateImage("+retResult+")");
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
    {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,proj,null,null,null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

}

Now, calling Java from my script works fine. I added a `onClick="Android.imageFromGallery()"`, and it correctly opens the Gallery.
BTW - It gives me the choice between Astro, File manager and Gallery. How can I limit it to Gallery so that it doesn't ask the user which file browser to use?

Anyway, the problem comes with Java calling Javascript to pass the result.
Apparently `updateImage()` (my JS function which simply shows the image name) gets no call from the Java code.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: solved the first issue - I can directly call the Gallery using

`Intent getImageFromGalleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`
`startActivityForResult(getImageFromGalleryIntent, 1);`

Comment: Have you tried `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:function(){ alert('working') }");` just to check if JS call is executed at all? It can be that you will have to wrap you JS calls in anonymous functions due to how webview might be treating call context. This is just a hunch.

Comment: Nope, the JS doesn't get called at all, even if I wrap it as you suggested :(

Comment: So next question: is loadUrl working? Try putting a real URL instead of JS call and see it it loads in your WebView.

Comment: That's a good thought, but unfortunately it doesn't work either. Apparently my onActivityResult function doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Just to be sure, put a full URL `"http://www.google.com"`. If that doesn't work then do you get any errors or warnings in LogCat? Is mWebView reference valid, etc. You will have to debug it as it looks that your issue lies not with invoking JS from Java, but somewhere else.

Comment: Dang! I'm dense!!!
I put the onActivityResult WITHIN the JavascriptInterface... it simply couldn't work... I moved it outside of that class and it works fine.
Thanks for the various suggestions, Audrius!

Comment: No problem. You'd better answer your own question now and mark it as accepted. It might help someone out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The mistake was to add the onActivityResult as a function inside the JavascriptInterface class, while it needed to be outside it, within the WebView definition.

(I couldn't answer to my own question before because my reputation isn't high enough, so I had to wait a few hours)

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {         
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {                
            if (requestCode == 1) 
            {
                Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
                String retResult = getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:updateImage('"+retResult+"')");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
    {
            String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,proj,null,null,null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public class JavaScriptInterface
    {    
        Context mContext;
        Uri currImageURI;
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void imageFromGallery()
        {    
            Intent getImageFromGalleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(getImageFromGalleryIntent, 1);
        }
    }

}
```